# redirect_url mismatch error when exchanging code for token

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, owin

I'm trying to implement exchanging a code for a token in my WebApi application with Fitbit. I keep getting the exception, `Message = "Redirect_uri mismatch: http://localhost:49294/api/... Visit https://dev.fitbit.com/docs/oauth2 for more information on the Fitbit Web API authorization process."`

#### RequestUserAuthorizationUrl

```
string authorizationLink;
try
{
    string[] scopes = {"profile", "activity", "heartrate", "weight", "location", "sleep", "nutrition"};
    authorizationLink = Authenticator().GenerateAuthUrl(scopes);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    AppUtils.LogException(" FitbitHandler/RequestUserAuthorizationUrl ", e);
    authorizationLink = string.Empty;
}
return authorizationLink;
```

#### GetUserToken

```
public async Task<OAuth2AccessToken> GetUserToken(string code)
{
    if (_requestToken != null)
        return _requestToken;

    _requestToken = await Authenticator().ExchangeAuthCodeForAccessTokenAsync(code);
    return _requestToken;
}
```

#### Authenticator

```
private OAuth2Helper Authenticator()
{
    var appCredentials = new FitbitAppCredentials
    {
       ClientId = _consumerKey,
       ClientSecret = _consumerSecret
    };
   return new OAuth2Helper(appCredentials, CallbackUrl);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your redirect url should match what you have provided in app settings.